# Problemas con el deploy heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

Estoy haciendo un deploy en heroku para poder ingresar a la ruta de `graphiql` ya que esta no me mostraba el playground en produccion. Lo que hice en local fue hacer un downgrade de la gema

`gem 'graphiql-rails', '1.7.0', group: [:development, :production]` a `gem 'graphiql-rails', '~> 1.4.11', group: [:development, :production]`

Pero luego mientras hago el deploy(que funciona bien con la version 1.7.0) esta falla mostrando el siguiente error:

```
       You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing

   your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the

   updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

   

   If this is a development machine, remove the /tmp/build_e0d9a471_/Gemfile freeze

   by running `bundle install --no-deployment`.

   

   The dependencies in your gemfile changed

   

   You have added to the Gemfile:

   * graphiql-rails (~> 1.4.11)

   

   You have deleted from the Gemfile:

   * graphiql-rails (= 1.7.0)

   Bundler Output: You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing

   your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the

   updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

   

   If this is a development machine, remove the /tmp/build_e0d9a471_/Gemfile freeze

   by running `bundle install --no-deployment`.

   

   The dependencies in your gemfile changed

   

   You have added to the Gemfile:

   * graphiql-rails (~> 1.4.11)

   

   You have deleted from the Gemfile:

   * graphiql-rails (= 1.7.0)

 !

 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.

 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.

 !     Push failed
```

Cuando reviso en local el gemfile como el .lock estan a la par en la instalacion de la version, pero al parecer en produccion no ocurre lo mismo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola despues de llorar muchos minutos, descubri una respuesta por alli y se debe hacer lo siguiente:

1. Guarda el nombre de tu HEROKU_APP_NAME(ejemplo: HEROKU_APP_NAME.herokuapp.com)
2. Remueve la app de heroku y vuelve a crear una nueva con el mismo HEROKU_APP_NAME anterior
3. Remueve el Gemfile.lock desde tu repo
4. Remueve el Gemfile.lock desde tu repo local
5. Corre bundle install
6. Commit los cambios al repo remoto(Gemfile.lock)
7. Corre git push heroku master o crea el deploy desde el dashboard de heroku